# Shell script reverse two concatenated variables?

Tags: string, bash, shell, concatenation

I just wanted to concatenate two string variables, but the output is somehow reversed. Would anyone please let me know why? Thanks!!

My shell script:

```
HEADER=`cat header-cp-match-src-file.csv`
echo header: $HEADER
HEADER="$HEADER,Hello,123456"
echo header: $HEADER
```

The output:

```
header: good_description,tranx count
,Hello,123456description,tranx count
```

The first line is correct, but the final output doesn't have the `"header:"` and the `",Hello,123456"` goes to the front of the string.

========== SOLUTION ==========

The file `header-cp-match-src-file.csv` is originally from Windows env, so it contains a `\r`, based on the suggestion, it works fine now after removing the `\r`. Thanks!!

```
HEADER=`cat header-cp-match-src-file.csv`
echo header: $HEADER
HEADER=${HEADER/$'\r'/}
HEADER="$HEADER,KEVIN,123456"
echo header: $HEADER
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? (please describe problem Y, not problem X you encounter when trying to solve Z believing that this will eventually solve Y).

Comment: The output doesnt look accurate - at least the 2nd line should have the words "header:" and "good" in it... have you copied the EXACT input and output into your question?

Comment: `header-cp-match-src-file.csv` has DOS line endings. The carriage return is retained as the last character of `HEADER` the first time it is set; the second time you print it, it causes `,Hello,123456` to be printed at the beginning of the line, overwriting the first part of the string.

Comment: Can you show us some sample input data?  It's easier to come up with an answer when we can replicate your problem.  Also, try piping the output through `od -c` to search for spurious carriage returns.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf & ghoti, thanks for your prompt reply, but that's exactly what I am doing and I am not quite sure what else I could add to the question.

Comment: @chepner, correct!! Solved, thanks!!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I like the way you think ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first variable probably contains a `\r` (part of MSWin end of line) at the end. Try removing it.

```
echo ${HEADER/$'\r'/}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly the problem and ur solution rock!!

Comment: Thanks mate, I would have died and not figure out this fix ... so hard to debug something like this! Long live stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first line of your file, just do:

```
read HEADER < header-cp-match-src-file.csv
```

It seems your file has dos line endings. You can, as mentioned in choroba's answer remove this silly `\r` (aka `^M`) as he showed you. Better yet would be to convert your file entirely using, e.g., the `dos2unix` utility or even use an explicit appropriate `IFS` with `read`:

```
IFS+=$'\r' read HEADER < header-cp-match-src-file.csv
```

Other than that: don't use uppercase variable names (where did you all get this habit from???), don't use backticks, use `$(...)` instead. E.g., your first line would look better as

```
header=$(cat header-cp-match-src-file.csv)
```

or even better as:

```
header=$(< header-cp-match-src-file.csv)
```

as it would not fork on an external `cat`.

And use more quotes! Your script would be much better written as:

```
IFS+=$'\r' read header < header-cp-match-src-file.csv
echo "header: $header"
header+="KEVIN,123456"
echo "header: $header"
```

or even replacing the `echo` with `printf`:

```
printf "header: %s\n" "$header"
```